# How to color between two curves?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the code below, I'm having problems:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
                xlabel=,
                ylabel=,
                enlargelimits,
                ytick=\empty,
                xtick={-1.19,2.38},
                xticklabels={$-1$,$2$}]
    \addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-1.19:4}] {-(1/6)*x^2+2};
    
    \addplot[name path=G,green,domain={-3:4}] {0.25*x^2};
    
    \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=-2.19:2.19}]
    ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The figure does  not correspond to the graphs you plot in your code.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I wanted to draw from the above code.

Comment: `compat=1.10` is very old - we are at `1.18` now. Have a look at your old answers and upvote the answers you like. When you accept an answer - you can also upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
                xlabel=,
                ylabel=,
                enlargelimits,
                ytick=\empty,
                xtick={-1.19,2.38},
                xticklabels={$-1$,$2$}]
    \addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-2*sqrt(6/5):4}] {-(1/6)*x^2+2};
    \addplot[name path=G,green,domain={-2*sqrt(6/5):4}] {0.25*x^2};
    \tikzfillbetween[of=F and G, split, every segment no 0/.style={pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50}, every segment no 1/.style={fill=none}] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Filled pattern between two curves]

Comment: This: `xtick={-1.19,2.38}, xticklabels={$-1$,$2$}` breaks my heart, but I left it :o)

Comment: Thanks, but not like the photo added.

Comment: I want it to look like the attached figure.

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad: "I wanted to draw from the above code". This answers your question as far as I am concerned. If you can not find the correct functions, then you will have better luck asking on a math site.